# Parse large CSV file in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a CSV file (~1gb, 10 million rows). I want to parse it in batches and then write the output to the new text/CSV file, where each line would be a JSON array.

```
val outputFile = new File(outputFileName)
val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))

Source
  .fromFile(fileName)
  .getLines()
  .grouped(batchSize)
  .foreach(chunk => {
    val jsonArray = doChunkTransformation(chunk)

    bw.write(jsonArray)
  })

bw.close()
```

Is that approach efficient? Or maybe I should wrap it with `Future`? I'm quite fresh with Scala, so maybe I'm not aware of all methods and solutions?

**Important Note**
Unfortunately, I'm limited and I cannot use any external library, so the solution has to be written in pure Scala.

Comment: In which sense this should be sufficient? Why Future? I really do not understand why some people is so reluctant to adding a external library, this wold be easily solved using something like **fs2** or **akka-sreams**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez we are using closed internal maven repository, where each library has to be verified.

Comment: @Forin I feel your pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only optimization i can think of - parallelized `doChunkTransformation` execution, offcourse if it's relatively expensive operation, otherwise it does not make sens because IO will take more.
For example:

```
        implicit val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
        val paralelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2

        val outputFile = new File(outputFileName)
        val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
        val timeout = 

        Source
        .fromFile(fileName)
        .getLines()
        .grouped(batchSize * paralelism)
        .foreach(chunk => {
            //Run computations in paralel.
            // Note parallelism level depends on exact `ExecutionContext` implementation 
            // In this example it will be equal to amount of processors multiplied by 2
            // Future.traverse preserve order
            val computations = Future.traverse(chunk.grouped(paralelism)) (smallChunk => Future(doChunkTransformation(smallChunk))) 
            val chunks = Await.result(computations).map(_.flatten), 1 minute)
            bw.write(jsonArray)
        })

        bw.close()
```

UPD:
I did not find any mentions about preserving original order in `Future.traverse` in docs: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html
But I've prepared example that shows that order remains the same: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DUvwX1CXTl2kxrcez3uDgw

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random

import scala.language.postfixOps

val random = new Random()
val computes = Future.traverse((1 to 10).toList) { num: Int => 
  val delay = random.nextInt(1000)
  println(s"Delay is $delay")
  Thread.sleep(delay)
  Future(num.toString)
}
println(Await.result(computes, 1 minute))
```

prints out at the end : `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`

Comment: The batchSize is defined by the user. Is `val jsonArray` in correct place? I'm asking, becasue it looks like it is not visible later, in `write`.    
Can you add short description to the body of foreach? And what about the order - I assume it is not kept?

Comment: It seems also that I don't have `flatten` function - I guess it is, becasue we are using 2.12.8 verson of scala.

Comment: @Forin  I don't know signature of `doChunkTransformation` - this code above is example. If `flatten` operation not found, probably because of return type. Could you specify it, please?

Comment: thanks for clarifying the code. One more question - where do you get `smallerChunk` from?

Comment: @Forin sorry my mistake after refactoring I forgot about - fixed it. Thank you for attention to details.

Comment: @Forin sorry once again - I just did final edit. Not necessary, you can wrap `doChunkTransformation` invokation with Future, like shown on example.

Comment: @Forin No no you need to have `smallerChunk => Future(doChunkTransformation(smallerChunk))` - `doChunkTransformation` does not need to return future, leave it as is.

Comment: @Forin let me, please, know if it helped. I'm very curious. Thank you!

Comment: The order in which operations are executed is unknown but the collection is always collected in order _(which makes the execution slower btw)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I have noticed one error - in `Future.traverse(chunk.grouped(...)` it sshould be `batchSize` not `paralelism`. Otherwise we are getting batchSize-length iterator with paralelism-length Seq.