# efficient feeder with preprocessing

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a huge csv file as a raw data source (¬14 gb). I want to create a scenario, where each request contains  `N` elements from my csv, parsed to JSON object and wrapped as JSON array.

What I have tried for now is to preprocess my csv file using `Future` and dump it to the new csv file under single column, as it is partially described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65845365/2290763
Then I'm using my output csv file (¬50gb) as a Gatling feeder and inject that single column as `StringBody`.

However, I'm not sure if it is the most efficient aproach. Earlier i have tried to use `readRecords`, but it was not taking to long.

Any ideas how to approach such load testing problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling you're headed the wrong way: trying to feed whole bodies, which results in humongous feeder files, instead of feeding values and injecting them into one of the templating engines Gatling supports, such as `StringBodies`, `ElFileBodies`, `PebbleStringBody` or `PebbleFileBody`. See https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request/#request-body

Comment: Probably you are right, however, I'm not sure if processing, let's say 1000 elements, before injection, when the test is running, is efficient. What I was thinking also is to preprocess my jsons into seperate file each, then create a csv file with filenames only and use `RawFileBody` to inject my json.

Comment: Looks like premature optimization to me. Until proven otherwise, there's no reason that reading lazily from a CSV file while the test is running is more efficient than computing the payload with a template. You should first give it a try and measure if you actually have an issue (there's a very good chance you don't).

Comment: Ok, but still I have to combine eg. 1k rows into objects and then create a single json array. How to do such a template?
I see now, that I can use templates as it is described in the docs.